# Should I include a junction table with a primary key in my ski rental database schema?

Tags: database-design, database-diagrams

I need to make the ER diagram and the relational schema of the Ski rentals. I have an `Customer`, `Rental` and `Ski` as a entities as well as their attributes. `Customers` and `Rentals` should have the one-to-many relationship and the relationship between `Rentals` and `Ski` should be many-to-many (one rental can have many skis and one ski can be rented to many customers). As I did some research on how to make the relational schema, I found out that it is mandatory to make the junction table `Rentals_skis` that include foreign keys from the `Rentals` and `Ski`. Is it necessary to add primary key to the junction table? Also, should I add new entity `Rentals_skis` in my ER diagram?

This is the links to my diagrams that I made using Dia.

Relational schema: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN66Q.jpg

ER diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lygV.jpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is it necessary to add primary key to the junction table?

Every table should have a primary key defined, to follow good database design. A table without one is a sign of denormalization. In your case, the primary key of the `Rental_skis` junction table is natural and would be defined on `(rental_id, ski_id)`, the combination of each foreign key field in this case. As it is not possible for the same `ski_id` to exist for the same `rental_id` more than once.

Note, by implementing this junction table, you'd no longer need the field `ski_id` to be stored directly in the `Rentals` table, and that column should be removed from that table in your design.

> Also, should I add new entity Rentals_skis in my ER diagram?

I would think so.

Answer (score -1):

No, the `Rental_skis' is not mandatory, it is actually opposite. It will be source of problems.
The ER diagram is more correct in this case and do not need to be updated.

The `Rentals` is already a junction table. It already has two foreign keys: `customer_id` and `ski_id`. They completely answer the question "who rented which ski at this moment of time?"

If you go by the schema showed (with `Rentals_skis`), then you can have a situation that `ski_id` in `Rentals` points to one ski, while `ski_id` in `Rentals_skis` points to another ski. In this case which one is correct? Which ski this customer rented?

And yes, the `Rentals` needs to have a primary key. You can go with `rental_id`, yes. But it would be better to use a compound key: `customer_id, start_date` or `ski_id, start_date`. The difference here is just point of view: what is more important - customer or ski.

Comment: The reason OP needs a junction table such as `Rental_skis` is for the requirements they described: "*one rental can have many skis*". You can't properly model that in a normalized way, in only the `Rentals` table alone.

Comment: "*If you go by the schema showed (with `Rentals_skis`), then you can have a situation that `ski_id` in `Rentals` points to one ski, while `ski_id` in `Rentals_skis` points to another ski.*" - The `ski_id` would no longer be stored directly in the `Rentals` table, with the `Rental_skis` junction table implementation. I've updated my answer to explicitly mention that now.

Comment: @J.D. Yes, one customer can rent many skis. The `Rentals` table already takes care of it. You can have as many records with same `customer_id` and `ski_id` in `Rentals` as you want, they would be identified by date the customer did the renting, hence suggestion to have `customer_id, start_date` as natural PK for `Rentals`.

Comment: If you put that scenario all in the same `Rentals` table, you'd have to repeat the same primary key value (either `(rental_id)` or the natural key you just suggested `(customer_id, start_date)`) multiple times - once for each ski rented in the same rental, breaking the primary key. It would also be in a denormalized form.

Comment: Why? How many skis a person can rent simultaneously??? A customer John can rent a blue ski on 1st day and red ski on second day. So the PKs would be `(1, '1/1/2023')` and `(1, '1/2/2023')` - same `customer_id`, different dates. John cannot rent red and blue together on the same day.

Comment: In the real world, nothing stops a single customer walking into a ski shop and renting all the skis for their friends in a single rental. From the ski shop's perspective it's a single rental tied to a single customer, with multiple skis. This aligns with the theoretical use cases that OP described: "*one rental can have many skis*".

Comment: oh... yeah... But in this case, the `ski_id` in `Rentals` should not exist.

Comment: Right, exactly why a junction table like `Rental_skis` would be needed.